# nagios event handler executing python script

Tags: python, nagios

I am stumped as to what this issue could be. The nagios log does not report any errors anymore but my file does not get written with anything.

```
def log_something(host_name host_address, attempt_number):
   with open('file', 'a+') as log:
       log.write('called function at %s with args %s' %s (str(datetime.datetime.now()), locals()))


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('host_name')
    parser.add_argument('host_address')
    parser.add_argument('attempt_number')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    log_something(args.host_name, args.host_address, args.attempt_number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And in my commands.cfg

```
define command {
    command_name my_command
    command_line $USER1$/my_command.py $HOSTNAME$ $HOSTADDRESS$ $HOSTATTEMPT$
}
```

And in my host config

```
define host {
    ...
    event_handler my_command
}
```

And in the nagios log (journalctl -xe)

```
OST ALERT: test-router;UP;HARD;5;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.96 ms
Jan 31 15:38:47 nagios-server.nagios[9212]: HOST EVENT HANDLER: test-router;UP;HARD;5;my_command
```

Nothing is written to the file, no errors are reported. When there were errors in my syntax the nagios log would print the errors that were reported to stderr, one of which was a file permission issue. I fixed that by creating the file in the same folder and chmod 777 everything. Besides if that was an issue it should be logged.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out. It seems as if you define where the output of nagios event handlers goes in the `nagios.cfg` file.

```
# TEMP PATH
# This is path where Nagios can create temp files for service and
# host check results, etc.
temp_path=/tmp
```

I think this means that the output of the plugin checks get sent to the temp folder. However, changing that path seems to have no effect and the result of my output in the python script still gets written as `file` in the /tmp folder. This is CentOS7.

Comment: Also worth noting that you should definitely be able to specify a full path in your script that would override wherever Nagios decides to place it. Also, are you logging event_handlers? `log_event_handlers=1` in `nagios.cfg`

Comment: i am logging event handlers, but they only log stuff when there's an error. stdout print statements in the function don't get sent to the log for some reason. I have tried to specify a path but it won't save there for some reason

Comment: it only ever saves in the `/tmp` directory no matter what path i give it, relative or absolute. I made a function that prints the log path and it's undoubtedly `/tmp`.

Answer (score -1):

Check you function, it seem you missing the "," in function parameters.

def log_something(**host_name host_address**, attempt_number):
   with open('file', 'a+') as log:

Comment: noted and fixed, turns out it isn't the issue though

Comment: cool, you fixed it, But how is this appropriate to give negative vote who tries to help you out, Anyways happy learning.

Comment: only because i specified in the question that no errors are reported, which if what you said was an issue, would have returned a wrong number of arguments type of error. and i know this sounds silly but I actually didn't mean to downvote you